# Where is p/process/Submit in salesforce

Tags: apex, javascript, email

I'm trying to modify a javascript button so that is send a message to more people. I came across this line of code

```
navigateToUrl('/p/process/Submit?id={!Invoice_Line__c.Id}&retURL=%2F{!Invoice_Line__c.AccountId__c}');
```

I'm just wondering where that could be.

Here is the code:

```
if ({!IF(Invoice_Line__c.RecordType == 'New Invoice', true, false)
    }) {
    if ({!AND(ISBLANK(Invoice_Line__c.Installation_Date__c), ISPICKVAL(Invoice_Line__c.Masterfile_Name__c, ''))
        })
        alert('Enter Installation Date and MasterFile Name');
    else if ({!ISBLANK(Invoice_Line__c.Installation_Date__c)
        })
        alert('Enter Installation Date');
    else if ({!NOT(ISPICKVAL(Invoice_Line__c.Masterfile_Name__c, ''))
        })
        alert('Enter MasterFile Name');
    else {
        if (confirm('Once you submit this record for approval, you might not be able to edit it or recall it from the approval process depending on your settings. Continue?')) {
            navigateToUrl('/p/process/Submit?id={!Invoice_Line__c.Id}&retURL=%2F{!Invoice_Line__c.AccountId__c}');
        }
    }
} else {


    if (confirm('Once you submit this record for approval, you might not be able to edit it or recall it from the approval process depending on your settings. Continue?')) {
        navigateToUrl('/p/process/Submit?id={!Invoice_Line__c.Id}&retURL=%2F{!Invoice_Line__c.AccountId__c}');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe after Winter'16 you can not use the Custom Buttons to call standard URL for Approval Process Submission (which is "/p/process/Submit?... ").  As a workaround you may need to use REST API to submit the approval.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000229821&language=en_US

Snippets from the link.

**"We need to confirm that your request is valid. Please repeat your last action" error when using button executing Javascript for Approval Process submission**

*Knowledge Article Number* - 000229821

*Description* - This is an intentional change which has been made by Salesforce in Winter'16 release to remove security vulnerability.

Staring Winter'16, you will not be able to use the Custom Buttons to call standard URL for Approval Process Submission (which is "/p/process/Submit?... ").

When you use this, you will get an error : "We need to confirm that your request is valid. Please repeat your last action"

This is working as designed.

*Resolution -* In order to make the custom buttons for Approval Process submission work, you will need to use Apex  or REST API  Winter'16 onwards.